# Error: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object while running Apache Beam Python

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to join two PCollections using Beam-Python based on the first col (say empnum) using cogroupbykey.
The schema/structure of the file is - `emp_num, emp_phone, emp_email, emp_country, emp_address`.
To achieve the need, I converted file data as `key,value` and then applied a `cogroupbykey` but I am getting below error.

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object [while running 'Merge/pair_with_oldemp']
```

Here is my code that I tried.

```
class splitrow(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, lines):
        row=lines.split(',')
        (key,value)=(row[0],(row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]))
        return [(key,value)]

# pipelineOptions
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

#Dataflow pipelines
oldemp = (p 
    | "ReadoldEMPfile" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://pybeam_bucket/oldemp.txt')
    | "SplitoldEMPFile" >> beam.ParDo(splitrow())
    | "Print1" >> beam.Map(print))
newemp = (p 
    | "ReadnewEMPfile" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://pybeam_bucket/newemp.txt')
    | "SplitnewEMPFile" >> beam.ParDo(splitrow())
    | "Print2" >> beam.Map(print))

empdata = (({'oldemp': oldemp, 'newemp': newemp})
  | 'Merge' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
  | beam.Map(print)
  )
```

Comment: Note that "Map(print)" doesn't output any element, hence there's nothing to join. Is that in the final code too?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see the final join result. That's what I put print statement.

Comment: But print1 and print2 (before the join) won't output anything, so there's nothing to join. I suggest to create your own function that simply prints and output the elements

Comment: @raj You can use beam.GroupByKey() instead of beam.CoGroupByKey() in the Merge Line.